# How do i override functions in a Vaadin 12 project? ValueProvider, SelectionListener and ComponentEventListener

Tags: java, overriding, spring-mybatis, vaadin12

This will be quite a bit of code as I don't know what will be important. I was trying to recreated the basic UI Alejandro made in my tutorial session with him a few months ago, substituting a table in my database for the one he used. The errors I'm getting all seem related to overriding Vaadin Flow functions. I know that replaces the behavior of the Super method. IntelliJ opens the relevant Super method when I click on the errors, which I'm assuming it wants me to edit to solve the problem, but I have no idea how to do that.

I was going to paste a link to the code but the forum told me to just place it here.

Customer.java

```java
package com.dbproject.storeui;

import java.time.LocalDate;

public class Customer {
    private Long id;
    private String lastname;
    private String firstname;
    private String email;
    private String password;
    private String phone;
    private String street;
    private String city;
    private String st;
    private int zip;
    private LocalDate dob;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getLastname() {
        return lastname;
    }

    public void setLastname(String lastname) {
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }

    public String getFirstname() {
        return firstname;
    }

    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public String getStreet() {
        return street;
    }

    public void setStreet(String street) {
        this.street = street;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public String getSt() {
        return st;
    }

    public void setSt(String st) {
        this.st = st;
    }

    public int getZip() {
        return zip;
    }

    public void setZip(int zip) {
        this.zip = zip;
    }

    public LocalDate getDob() {
        return dob;
    }

    public void setDob(LocalDate dob) {
        this.dob = dob;
    }
}
```

CustomerRepository.java

```java
package com.dbproject.storeui;

import org.apache.ibatis.annotations.*;

import java.util.List;

@Mapper
public interface CustomerMapper {

    @Select("SELECT * FROM customer ORDER BY id")
    List<Customer> findAll();

    @Update("UPDATE customer" +
            "SET lastname=#{lastname}, firstname=#{firstname}, email=#{email}, password=#{password}, phone=#{phone}, street=#{street}, city=#{city}, st=${st}, zip=#{zip}, dob=#{dob}" +
            "WHERE id=#{id}")
    void update(Customer customer);

    @Insert("INSERT INTO customer(lastname, firstname, email, password, phone, street, city, st, zip, dob) VALUES(#{lastname}, #{firstname}, #{email}, #{password}, #{phone}, #{street}, #{city}, #{st}, #{zip}, #{dob})")
    @Options(useGeneratedKeys = true, keyProperty = "id")
    void create(Customer customer);
}
```

CustomerView.java (the UI class)

```java
package com.dbproject.storeui;

import com.vaadin.flow.component.Composite;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.button.Button;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.grid.Grid;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.icon.VaadinIcon;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.notification.Notification;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.orderedlayout.VerticalLayout;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.textfield.TextField;
import com.vaadin.flow.data.binder.Binder;
import com.vaadin.flow.router.Route;

@Route("")
public class CustomerView extends Composite<VerticalLayout> {

    private final CustomerMapper customerMapper;

    private Grid<Customer> grid = new Grid<>();
    private TextField lastname = new TextField("Last Name");
    private TextField firstname = new TextField("First Name");
    private Button save = new Button("Save", VaadinIcon.CHECK.create());
    private Button create = new Button("New", VaadinIcon.PLUS.create());
    private VerticalLayout form = new VerticalLayout(lastname, firstname, save);

    private Binder<Customer> binder = new Binder<>(Customer.class);
    private Customer customer;

    public CustomerView(CustomerMapper customerMapper) {

        this.customerMapper = customerMapper;

        grid.addColumn(Customer::getLastname).setHeader("Last Name");
        grid.addColumn(Customer::getFirstname).setHeader("First Name");
        grid.addSelectionListener(event -> setCustomer(grid.asSingleSelect().getValue()));
        updateGrid();

        save.addClickListener(event -> saveClicked());
        create.addClickListener(event -> createClicked());

        getContent().add(grid, create, form);
        binder.bindInstanceFields(this);
        binder.setBean(null);
    }

    private void createClicked() {
        grid.asSingleSelect().clear();
        setCustomer(new Customer());
    }

    private void saveClicked() {
        binder.readBean(customer);
        if (customer.getId() == null) {
            customerMapper.create(customer);
        } else {
            customerMapper.update(customer);
        }
        updateGrid();
        Notification.show("Saved!");
    }

    private void setCustomer(Customer customer) {
        this.customer = customer;
        form.setEnabled(customer != null);
        binder.setBean(customer);
    }

    private void updateGrid() {
        grid.setItems(customerMapper.findAll());
    }
}
```

Comment: what exactly are these errors that you are getting?

Comment: I had another chat session with Alejandro after this. He told me that the red dots I was seeing next to the line numbers of that code weren't indicating a "Warning". It was simply an "Info" telling me which methods the code on those lines was overriding. I'm so used to IDEs only saying something when there's a problem that I thought I had to take some action to fix it. I am still having a problem but it's with the save button. If I edit the first or last names, in the text boxes and then click the save button, it silently fails. Like `saveClicked()` fails to execute.

Comment: Turns out the problem with the save button wasn't actually the button, it was with the @Update SQL statement in CustomerRepository.java (which I've since renamed CustomerMapper.java). I forgot how to concatenate and didn't leave a space at the end of the first string. Also, there was a $ in the st part that should've been a #. I've changed a few things such as adding the rest of the columns in Customer to the form and subsequently changed the TextField for email to an EmailField, PasswordField for password, NumberField for zip, and DatePicker for DOB.